# Display image from server site to client side with axios get request Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to preview images, which I am getting from an axios get request. The format is encoded how to convert it.

Response format : 
    pic:"RPNNKU91S7WMY9X1O15DZNH74ZWMZ1G9NRQJYGMUXTWAJQ3SUE3NVSCOJEGMTOAY70N3ONP1FUZHSSYSQERSOD8OVSSU6Q85XOLJP64NG6PGS0KRBHC7WQFUBZBCA2RH.jpeg"

```
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://api',
            {
                headers: { "Token": "23yh"}
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data,"res");
                this.setState({
                   pic: response.data.pic,
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }


      <Col>
          <img height="50" width="43" alt="logo"
             src={this.state.pic}                  
           />
     </Col>
```

Comment: Looks like your API returns the filename of the image, but URLs (unless they are relative to the current page) require a hostname etc, perhaps you mean to set `src=http://api/{this.state.pic}`?

Comment: yes thats file name now i got it thankyou